# Mocking methods used in Static Methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to stop a method that sends an email from actually sending the email and I think that mock objects (or some variant) are the way to go. Here is the situation:

```
class UserModel {

    public static function resetPassword()
    {
      // Code to generate new password, etc, etc

      self::_sendMail($to, $body);
      return 1;
    }

    private function _sendMail($to, $body)
    {
      // Send email
    }
}
```

Is there anyway in PHPUnit that I can mock _sendMail() and inject my own code so I can properly test the other logic in resetPassword() ?

My test would simply look something like:

```
$this->assertTrue(UserModel::resetPassword());
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why the downvote? Have I asked the question poorly?

Comment: Looks like the downvote was removed (:

Answer (score 2):

I think this is how you'd do it

```
class MockUserModel extends UserModel
{
    static function _sendMail( $to, $body )
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

then

```
$this->assertTrue( MockUserModel::resetPassword() );
```

But I'm not a unit testing guru, so I apologize if this leads you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Of course.. these things are so simple once they're right in front of your face. Thanks a lot Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You could restructure the original code. It becomes clearer and more testable.

```
class UserModel
{
    public static function resetPasswordAndSendMail()
    {
      if (!self::resetPassword()) {
        return false;
      }
      self::_sendMail($to, $body);
      return true;
    }

    public static function resetPassword()
    {
      // Code to generate new password, etc, etc
      return true;
    }

    private static function _sendMail($to, $body)
    {
      // Send email
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it useful to utilize the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) here.  See [Mocking/stubbing FTP operations in PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318133/212218) for a similar scenario and some other possible solutions.